# Nginx tries to open static files instead of proxying them

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a very simple setup and I need to combine two websites into one, the problem is that static assets are not loaded.

I see that nginx is trying to open them, however they should be redirected from the proxied website. I tried with/without trailing slash, with `$request_uri` and without and still cannot load css.

Example log

```
2018/02/05 15:38:39 [error] 37#37: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/css/styles.gz.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /css/styles.gz.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

My nginx config

```
location /css/ {
  proxy_pass https://myotherwebsite.com/css; # css is in CSS folder so I want to proxy the whole thing
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
location /faq {
  proxy_pass https://myotherwebsite.com/service/faq; # HTML loads, css not
}
```

Comment: I believe you should better provide your full nginx config. It seems you location does't work properly.

Comment: Please show the complete `server` block.

Comment: using `location /css/ { proxy_pass https://myotherwebsite.com/css/ [...]` works for me... looks like problem is elsewhere.  But you need to match /css/ with proxy_pass .../css/